# Am I returning error status correctly?

Tags: perl, exit-code

I have this snippet at the end of my script:

```
use List::Util qw(min max);
// more stuff..
my $maxReturnCode = max @retCodes;
print "Highest Error Code: $maxReturnCode\n";

exit($maxReturnCode >>8) unless $maxReturnCode == 0;
exit(0);
```

I add error codes during a threaded compilation:

```
my $cmd = "$MAKE $MAKE_INVOCATION_PATH/$comp";
my $retCode = system($cmd);
push(@retCodes, $retCode);
```

However, when I print the highest error code at the end, it's just blank:

```
01-Apr-2014 06:03:25    Ended At: 06:03 AM
01-Apr-2014 06:03:25    
01-Apr-2014 06:03:25    Highest Error Code:
```

Am I converting this wrong?

Comment: What if it's killed by a signal? That will result in `exit(0)` (success), even though it isn't. `sh` does something like `($? & 0x7F) ? (($? & 0x7F) | 0x80) : ($? >> 8)`.

Answer (score 1):

The returncode of system() calls is in **$?**

Use `$? >> 8` to get the real exit value of your system call.

```
my $cmd = "$MAKE $MAKE_INVOCATION_PATH/$comp";
my $retCode = system($cmd);
push(@retCodes, $?>>8) if $retCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$maxReturnCode` is undef because `@retCodes` is empty. Either you never reached that `push`, or you have two variables named `@retCodes`.

You did mention threads, are you trying to pass values from one thread to the other via `@retCodes`? Did you make it shared?